# I need to filter by literally a date Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, filter

It doesn't return anything. I have two dates, if it's one the order it's open, if not is closed... but it returns me the list I have by default

```
if ($request->has('searchByStatus') && $request->input('searchByStatus') === 'open')
{ echo 'in open';
    $req1=$request->get('searchByStatus');
   
    $search = MaintenanceTasks::select(
        'Employee_Id_created',
        'Task_Id',
        'Machine_Id',
        'Request_date',
        'Start_date_reparation'
    )
   ->where('Start_date_reparation','like' ,'1999-11-11 00:00:00')
   ->get();
   dump($search);
}
}

return view('/otList', [
    'searchByStatus'=>$req1,
    'search'=>$search
]);
```

on blade.php

```
<select type="text" name="searchByStatus">
    <option selected disabled>Select</option>
    <option id="open">Open</option>
    <option id="closed">Closed</option>           
</select>
@foreach($search as $otList)
    @if(($otList->getDateString() == '1999-11-11 00:00:00'))
        <label>Open</label>
    @else
        <label>Closed</label>   
    @endif
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I think [if you read this it will help you solve at least some of this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this code.

If your $request is Request then it does'nt have that signature: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_has

Use $req1->has('searchByStatus') to check existence property. After $request->input('searchByStatus') === 'open' and run your query.

To get only one column use 'pluck': https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values

```
if ($request->has('searchByStatus') && request->input('searchByStatus') === 'open') {
    $tasks = MaintenanceTasks::query()
            ->where('Start_date_reparation', '1999-11-11 00:00:00')
            ->pluck('Start_date_reparation');
} else if ($request->has('searchByStatus') && request->input('searchByStatus') === 'closed') {
    $tasks = MaintenanceTasks::query()
                ->where('Start_date_reparation', '!=', '1999-11-11 00:00:00')
                ->pluck('Start_date_reparation');
}
```

Also, to check your result you may to use dd($tasks): https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd

Comment: It's filtering but not showing. I return on my view  'searchByStatus'=>$query, 'search'=>$task.
It shows only with dd.

Comment: May be you use mistaken variables. Pass to the view $tasks. It the given status is necessary then pass it also. Example: return view('view.name', ['tasks' => $tasks, 'status' => request->input('searchByStatus')]). You use $query as a status, $search as tasks. The result contains only values of Start_date_reparation. I don't kown the ->getDateString() function in Carbon or DateTime. May be your blade has a mistake. Can you give a result of your dd()?

Comment: my dd shows the correct request, but it doesn't shows me on a list  idk why. I mean on my filter's table

Comment: Do you use this condition? @if(($otList == '1999-11-11 00:00:00')) What format of the dates in the result?

Comment: yes, I'm using it on my blade. Now I've changed my return view but it still not working

Comment: I will edit my ask with the changes I made

Comment: What is html output? Variables $req1 and $search will be undefined if this condition will be false. It is wrong.

Comment: they're defined   $req1=$request->has('searchByStatus'); but now I'm realizing what $search is not working. I thought I've defined with the query ($search=MaintenanceTasks::...)
And the filter only works when I comment the rest of the filters.

Comment: Do you use more one filters? If it is true then you have another code after the condition.

Comment: yes, but the other filters are working correctly

Comment: My answer for one filter. Initial query should be defined in the start of the function. $query = MaintenanceTasks::query() or $query = MaintenanceTasks::select(...). After need to build the query in your block conditions: $query->where(...), $query->where(...). In the end need to call query: $query->get().